# Build configuration in CLion

Tags: clion

How can I create a build configuration for release build (with optimizations, etc.)
The project is imported from existing sources, with a custom `CMakeLists.txt` file.

In the *Edit Configurations* window, only "Debug" appears as configuration, with no way to add another configuration.

[image: screenshot]

The `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(epi CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(SYSTEM external/include)
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare)

file(GLOB_RECURSE EPI_SRC "src/*")
add_executable(epi ${EPI_SRC})
target_link_libraries(epi ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `File` ->  `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `CMake`. There you'll be able to more build configurations.